# Set minimum zoom level for MapView

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

Is there a way I can set a minimum zooM level for my MapView?. The map looks really ugly when zoom level is set to one because the whole world map replicated.

I would like to block that zoom level. Ideally, it would work whether the user is zooming through gestures or zoom controls.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fortunately, i was having an overlay in my MapView. Otherwise, i guess you will have to create one, just for this tiny feature :-/. I wonder why there isn't any other way of doing this easier.

Anyways, you just need to override your draw method like this:

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < 2)
            mapView.getController().setZoom(2);
    }
```

Ger

Answer (score 3):

Similar to **ggomeze's** answer by overriding a `*draw()` method but it may be better to override `dispatchDraw()` in `MapView`. This way you can block the draw for the zoom level where the tiles are empty.

Also note that its good to center the map at this point as if you  are zooming with touch gestures manually setting the zoom out by one level can cause the map to shift away from the center each time (which makes the `MapView` look a bit more dodgy!).

```
@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    //limit zoom level 
    if(getZoomLevel() == 1){
        getController().setZoom(2);
        getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(0, 0));
        //dont draw as it will just be blank and then jump
        return;
    }

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

This could be improved upon by tracking the zoom level while the gesture is taking place also so the user can not see the partial zoom to the blocked lowest zoom level (1) while gesturing but i imagine the case above will suit most and is a lot easier!

Answer (score -4):

just write onCreate following code:

```
MapController myMC myMapView.getController();
myMC.setZoom(int value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, this is not a solution to my problem. With that code you are just setting the initial zoom level. But that doesn't avoid the user can zoom out, and have that ugly map view with a zoom level equals to 1 (two africas, two americas)

Comment: if u are not looking for standart option only, set limiter manualy :)

Comment: Why are you limiting what the user can do? What if they want to see the whole world?

Comment: I allow the user to see the whole world (zoom = 2), but don't want to let them see it twice (zoom = 1)