# MapActivity - How to restrict zoom levels?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I implemented a `MapActivity` with Pins on it, following [HelloMapView Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) and many StackOverflow resources.

For the purpose of my app, I would like to **limit the zoom levels** with a minimum and a maximum. In fact I would like to avoid using `android:clickable="true"` on my MapView.

I could not find how do achieve that.

- Is it possible?
- Does someone knows how to do that?
- Is there a built-in function to override like `onZoomChanged()` that I did not see?

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="16"
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

#### MyMapActivity.java

```
// Here is my MapView
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.game_map);
mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
mMapView.setSatellite(true);
mMapController = mMapView.getController();
mMapController.setZoom(CONST_MAP_ZOOM);
mMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(48856700, 2351000));
mMapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(48856700, 2351000));
```

But when I use fingers, I can zoom out until I see the whole planet.

What I would like would be to limit the zoom levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way out.

I disable multi-touche on the MapView:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/game_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_api_key"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Then I hide zoom controls:

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.game_map);
mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Then I implement my own zoom controls.

Answer (score 1):

MapView does have on onSizeChanged

see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)

Perhaps you could listen for that and then call getZoomLevel() and see if it's in your acceptable range and change it from there.

Or better yet, you could override the onDraw and always check it there.
[Set minimum zoom level for MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146395/set-minimum-zoom-level-for-mapview)

Comment: My Eclipse won't let me implement this... Not on MapView nor MapViewController.

Comment: There is a lot going on. Did you already walk through the HelloMapView tutorial? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: Yes I did, my map works very well, with pins and circles around them. I just would like to limit the zoomOut by touch...

Comment: Since what API is onSizeChanged available? Is there a setOnSizeChaned method? I can't find those info in the documentation...