# Android Map Scaling

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to make an app that uses Google maps API mapviews and my problem is that when building the app I realized that the roads on Google maps scale down on zoom in and wondering if there is any way to disable this scaling as I want the full size of the roads on maximum zoom. Hopefully this picture will clear any misunderstandings:

[image: The road to be it's maximum size in its maximum zoom]

Comment: That would be very difficult considering you don't get any contextual information from the tile (like what are the road vectors, labels, etc). So I would suspect the answer to your question would be no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you will be satisfied with the result from what you are trying to do, fixing the zoom to a specific value, which will resukt in a very pour user experience ...

But if you really want to give it a try, just use the one of the solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146395/set-minimum-zoom-level-for-mapview)

good luck.

Comment: thanks for the help the post kinda of gave me the idea on what to do.