# Set minimum zoom for kivy garden mapview in python side

Tags: python, kivy, zooming, android-mapview

I have a map like this in my main file:

```
mapview = MapView(zoom=5, lat=14.0583, lon=108.2772)
self.add_widget(mapview)
```

How I can set the minimum zoom for the map? Thank you for you help.

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146395/set-minimum-zoom-level-for-mapview

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explain how to do this:

https://mapview.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.4/

Reading it tells you that you can create your class like this:

```py
MapView(
  zoom = 11,
  lat = 50.6394,
  lon = 3.057,
  map_sourcev = MapSource(max_zoom = 11, min_zoom = 5)
)
```

Do not forget to always take a look at the documentation.